# Open custom camera, take picture, save picture, send picture

Tags: java, android, email, camera, sd-card

I have a question this time around regarding the Android custom camera, NOT the built in camera that is accessible through Camera_intent.  I am not permitted to use that one.  What I am attempting to do is allow a user to aim the camera at something and choose "Send" on the onOptionsItemMenu.

I am not having any issues getting this implemented...separately.  If I ask it to send something with the click of a button, it sends.  If I tell the camera to save the picture without sending it, it does.

I run into a problem when I try to do both.  As it stands, using this code:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent i;
        File file2;
        camera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.save:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        case R.id.send:

            file2 = new File(filename);
            i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample Picture");
            System.out.println("file//" + file2);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file//" + file2));
            i.setType("image/png");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Email file"));
            finish();
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

The camera "clicks" or "flickers" as if it is taking the picture and then it immediately opens the mail client choose.  When I select which I want to take Gmail is saying that the location is null.  However if I remove the part that starts the email chooser, the image saves properly and is there.

Almost as if it is skipping over that camera taking step.

Im sure the solution to this is simple, I just have a baked brain right now and probably can't see the forest because of the trees. (if that is even how that analogy is said).

Do I run the camera part on another thread?

An idea I had was to use a boolean to check for the file's existence and size, but I am unsure how to make the program check that over and over again until it returns true.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the built in camera app?

Comment: Yes, there is, I need to use the custom camera because I have a surfaceview overtop of it.  Sort of a graphical overlay that a person can move around and resize.  When they take the picture I have the overlay and the "photo" merging together to be saved or sent off.  I have successfully implemented a version that uses the native camera FIRST and then lets you move the overlay around and so forth...BUT the person who I am making this for doesn't want it that way.  Trust me, obscenities have been bouncing around in my brain since the turned they working copy down.

Comment: Haha I know that feeling. I'm guessing what might be happening is that your callback is occurring on a separate thread. So, your "open mail client" action is occurring while your image is still being saved. What you should try, is have a flag of some sort that tells you if you are doing a send or save. Set this in the onOptionsItemSelected before you open the camera.. Then, in your mPictureCallback have that perform your ACTION_SEND intent (or save action). Make sense?

Comment: OHHH yeah.  I get it now. something like if "send" is chosen a flag then after the file is saved : if("flag" is set) start mail chooser with such and such file as an extra.

Comment: Right.. what I would try is to copy your code you have under your "case R.id.send" and put it at the end of your "takePicture" method just to try it out. (make sure to comment out the original code). Let me know if that works

Comment: I believe I am 90% there. it is taking the picture and preparing the email to be sent, using your idea.  I changed it a little bit and just used a switch statement.  Where an int (appropriately) named flag would be set to a 1 or 2 etc... and at the tail end of the callback, after the image is saved, the switch runs and the chooser opens.  The attachment on the email is the proper file name, but it's an empty file.  That, however, I can deal with myself.  I can't be begging for all the answers ;-)  But your method worked exactly how I needed it to.  If you want, submit it as an actual answer.

Comment: Haha, I'm a dunce.  it's file:// NOT file//

Comment: simple mistake yet so easy to miss. glad you caught it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing what might be happening is that your callback is occurring on a separate thread. So, your "open mail client" action is occurring while your image is still being saved. What you should try, is have a flag of some sort that tells you if you are doing a send or save. Set this in the onOptionsItemSelected before you open the camera.. Then, in your mPictureCallback have that perform your ACTION_SEND intent (or save action)